# Best practices to avoid Jenkins error: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins, sudo

When running any sudo command from Jenkins I get the following error: `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`.

I understand that I can solve this by adding a **NOPASSWD** entry to my `/etc/sudoers` file which will allow user **jenkins** to run commands without needing a password. I can add an entry like this:

```
%jenkins ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:/home/me/dir/script.sh
```

...but this leads to the following issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414330/how-to-avoid-specifying-full-path-in-sudoers-file

I can add an entry like this:

```
%jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

...but this allows user jenkins to avoid the password prompt for **ALL** commands, which seems a bit unsafe. I'm just curious what my options are here, and if there are any best practices I should consider.

Comment: I could not get which file you are changing with this command?

%jenkins ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:/home/vts_share/test/sudotest.sh

I am trying to use sudo command also in jenkins, so I need to know which file I should run this command?

Comment: It was a specific file on my machine, I've edited the post to show a generic file

Answer (score 14):

The no tty thing (`requiretty` in *sudoers*) is the real issue.

Basically, comment out the following lines in your */etc/sudoers* file:

```
#Defaults    requiretty
#Defaults   !visiblepw
```

Other ways to get it to work:

```
Defaults    !requiretty
```

Or per user:

```
Defaults:jenkins !requiretty
```

A more detailed answer is [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49078/56148) to this question on the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange site:

- [Why does cron silently fail to run sudo stuff in my script? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49077/why-does-cron-silently-fail-to-run-sudo-stuff-in-my-script)

Comment: My /etc/sudoers file does not contain either of those lines, but even after adding lines to sudoers to allow my user to use a command, I still get the "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified" error.

Answer (score 4):

One thing you can do is to get Jenkins to run a script, for example 'run.sh', 
then from inside this script you can start makefiles, and make sure that there are no sudo commands inside the makefiles.

It is a bit of a hassle, but at least you are not risking changing security settings